# Code will never be executed error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication

Xcode displays the warning that the code will never be executed, however I don't understand why. Can anyone enlighten me? (The error occurs in the inner if and else statements, inside the completion handler, for both validation statements)

```
- (IBAction)siginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (isLogin)
{
    [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:_usernameTextField.text
                           password:_passwordTextField.text
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error)
         {
             if (FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound)
             {
                 _credentialVerification.text = @"Invalid Credentials";
                 _entryValidation.text = @"An account with the listed credentials was not found, please proceed to registration screen via the navigation bar at the top of the applications user interface";
             }
             else
             {
 /*(Warning 1)*/ _credentialVerification.text = @"Valid Credentials";
                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainScreen" sender:self];
             }
         }

     ];
}
else
{
    [[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:_usernameTextField.text
                               password:_passwordTextField.text
                             completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error)
         {
             if (FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail)
             {
                 _credentialVerification.text = @"Invalid Email";
             }
             else
             {

 /*(Warning 2)*/ _entryValidation.text = @"Account creation was succesful, please proceed to the login screen via the navigation bar at the top of the applications user interface";
             }
         }

     ];
}
```

}

Edited:

```
- (IBAction)siginButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
if (isLogin)
{
    [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:_usernameTextField.text
                           password:_passwordTextField.text
                         completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error)
                         {
                             if (error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound)
                             {
                                 _credentialVerification.text = @"Invalid Credentials";
                                 _entryValidation.text = @"An account with the listed credentials was not found, please proceed to registration screen via the navigation bar at the top of the applications user interface";
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 _credentialVerification.text = @"Valid Credentials";
                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainScreen" sender:self];
                             }
                         }
     ];
}
else
{
    [[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:_usernameTextField.text
                               password:_passwordTextField.text
                             completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error)
                             {
                                 if (error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail)
                                 {
                                     _credentialVerification.text = @"Invalid Email";
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     _entryValidation.text = @"Account creation was succesful, please proceed to the login screen via the navigation bar at the top of the applications user interface";
                                 }
                             }
     ];
}
}
```

Comment: In which line where is this warning?

Comment: I will edit the code to show where the warnings appear.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava you should now be able to see the updated code, wherein the location of both errors is shown. Note: everything within the else statement is, technically, applicable to this "Code will never be executed" error, so editing what's inside won't yield any results, something is wrong with the external syntax, I believe.

Comment: Posted my answer. Check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is you are checking on the enumeration as the value of enumeration is non zero so it will always be true and would not enter else part, so you need to change the conditions in both if statements to check the error code like this (I am not sure about the syntax but hopefully you can get the idea)

```
if (error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound)
if (error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail)
```

**Update**

Modify you if else statements as follows:

```
if (error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error)
}else {
       //code when there is no error    
}
```

Comment: This was extremely informative, short and beneficial. Thank you.

Comment: I'm encountering a problem wherein both the if and else statement's are executed. By this, I mean the text boxes change values to the values stored in the if statement, but the transition still takes place to the next view controller...

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse this is different question, but anyways please show the updated code that you are using

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse add print(error.code) before each if statement and tell me the output and please remove the code from you posted as an answer, I have edited the question

Comment: I'm using NSLog(@"%ld", (long)error.code);
 instead, as the print function gives me the "Declaration of implicit..." error.

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse what is the output?

Comment: 17008 is the output

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse this is code for invalide email ,so in this case does it enter else part ?

Comment: Registration works fine because, in the else statement, there is no transition anywhere. What happens is, if you type a phoney, email address and it's obviously incorrect, it displays nothing at the bottom and the "Invalid Email" goes live. However, for the login, it still transitions, even after the "Invalid Email" briefly shows (displays as it transitions).

Comment: Yes, it, technically, enters the else part as there is no transition linked to the button itself, but to the view controller.

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse ok let me understand , you only want to execute else part when there is no error returned from the server, right?

Comment: hold on, when I do the same on the login screen, I now get code 17020

Comment: Yes, I only want to execute else when there is no error returned.

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse see my updated answer, see if that what you want

Comment: this gives me the error "use of undeclared identifier "null""

Comment: @TrojanTheHorse Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You are no where checking the completion handler `NSError` and that is why this warning is given by compiler. So, check it like this in your `signInWithEmail`

```
                          if (error.code == FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound)
                             {
                                 _credentialVerification.text = @"Invalid Credentials";
                                 _entryValidation.text = @"An account with the listed credentials was not found, please proceed to registration screen via the navigation bar at the top of the applications user interface";
                             }
                             else
                             {
                _credentialVerification.text = @"Valid Credentials";
                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMainScreen" sender:self];
                             }
```

And same for your `createUserWithEmail`  . Hope it helps you.

Comment: Along with the other answer, this was extremely informative, thank you.

Comment: Although, the behaviour is now that, even though it displays the error statement, what happens is that it does the else anyway...